# Google Maps GMSGroundOverlay shape of state or country

Tags: swift, google-maps, swift3, maps, gmsgroundoverlay

I would like to place an image on google maps so that it fits the shape of the country or state that it is placed in. I've been looking in to the GMSGroundOverlay as a potential way of accomplishing this, but I can't figure out an easy way to make the overlay take on the shape of a state/country. I was hoping someone might have a suggestion on how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think there's a very simple way of doing it, but check out [this link](http://blog.mastermaps.com/2011/02/natural-earth-vectors-in-cloud.html) where you can get the data for vector points you can use to create polygons in the shape of whatever region you want. I don't know if its the easiest way to do what you want, but it is a possibility and you should check it out.